# Parser in C#. How to populate a class from strings

Tags: c#, class, parsing

I'm trying to do a simple parser that receive an array and return a class with populated members.

I have the following class implementing the following interface.

```
    public class ReturnedObject : IReturnedObject
{
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
}

    public interface IReturnedObject
{
        string Source { get; set; }
        string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

If for example I receive the following line:

- command -source value1 -destination value2

I would like to be able to associate the source value and the destination value.

The main method look like this:

```
        private static IReturnedObject Parse<T>(string[] userArgs, ICommandesUtils commandUtils) where T : IReturnedObject, new()
    {
    //userArgs contains the folling array
    //command
    //-source
    //value1
    //-destination
    //value2

    //some work...

    IReturnedObject returnedObject = new T();

    returnedObject.Source = userArgs[2];
    returnedObject.Destination = userArgs[4];   
    }
```

What i'm looking for is a way to replace the two following lines :

```
returnedObject.Source = userArgs[2];
returnedObject.Destination = userArgs[4];
```

I want to do something like:

1. For each member of the class returnedObject
2. Look the name of the member (for example, "Destination")
3. Find in the userArgs the good value to assiociate (the one after "-destination" in this example)
4. Associate the value.

Is that possible ?
Thank you by advance :)

Comment: I suspect this is for a console application? If so have you considered: https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline

Comment: Your steps look like they make sense. You basically have three things - iterating over the properties, finding the values and setting the values. Are you having problems with all three parts or just the bits that involve inspecting your `returnedObject`? Basically the finding the right value from the args seems to be completely separate from setting the values so I'm just checking that you have that bit right...

Comment: This is a class library wich will be used by a console  application. I dont want to use external Package. The idea is to make my own :).

Comment: Yes the problem are this 3 parts. Clay07g answered my question using Reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.90).aspx) for this.

First of all, you should store the arguments in a better way. Use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> args; // Key = Property Name -- Value = Property Value
```

Then, for your logic, do:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = T.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach(var prop in props)
{
    string propName = prop.GetMethod.Name;

    if (args.ContainsKey(propName))
    {
        prop.SetValue(returnedObject, args[propName]);
    }
}
```

The values and logic can be edited to support any value types.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out Go Commando - http://mookid.dk/oncode/gocommando

```
Install-Package GoCommando
```

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Go.Run();
    }
}

[Command("do-stuff")]
[Description("I've no idea what we're doing")]
public class WhiteRussian : ICommand
{
    [Parameter("Source")]
    public double Source { get; set; }

    [Parameter("Destination")]
    public double Destination { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Do stuff with Source and Destination.
    }
}
```

Then run

```
stuff.exe do-stuff -source ketchup -destination italy
```

Comment: Thx but I dont want to use external Package. I should have specified that point.